# Constraint saying all elements of vector has to be >= 0 in scipy optimization

Tags: optimization, scipy

The input vector is x, which contains 5 elements and I want to optimize (minimize) a function with a constraint that **all elements of x should be greater than or equal to 0**.
ie., `x[i] >= 0` for `1 <= i <= 5`
In one of the answer I saw this and used in my code, but the answer is returning negative values also

```
def constraint2(x):
    """constrain all elements of a to be >= 0"""
    return x

cons2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2}
```

Where am I going wrong? How to enforce the constraint?

Comment: Using constraints for this task implies having n constraints for n variables. The above is not even API-compatible. If constraints should be used at all or better variable-bounds is solver specific and your code-snippet lacks all context there is.

Answer (score 0):

```
all(ele >= 0 for ele in x)
```

Try this